# How to use width of block with respect to inside content in css

Tags: css

I have a parent div which has two div inside one is image and one is description like below snapshot

[image]

The parent div has property`text-align: center`. so its working fine and text image and description is in center.

the description div has a property`max-width: 580px`. so if the description text increases, the image will slightly move to the left as below snapshot
[image]

And it looks good. But when there is some long word which does not fit in the current line it uses the whole `580px width` and long word goes into the next line, like below

[image]

since the whole description width is used so the image shifts to the left by using the parent property `text-align: center`.

but it does not looks good since its in the center by css logic but not by looks.

Is there a way to take the whole width only when there is some content.

I have used property `display: table-caption` and now it takes only the text width
[image]

and its in the center of the parent div.

but then it splits the `Assistant Manager` into two line like below which i dont want

[image]

Is there a way to implement the above task by some css property, or i have to use javascript to implement the above task.

Comment: We can't help by just seeing images. Please provide necessary code or jsfiddle to see the issue in action. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide us with any code, I only could guess.

This is what I came up with: https://jsfiddle.net/9888d4tf/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="headline-wrapper">
    <img class="headline-image" src="http://kcdn.at/company/84085/1073352/logo-fairmoney-clever-consulting-gmbh.companybig.gif">
    <p class="headline-title">
        <span>
            Assistant&nbsp;Manager someveryverylonglongtexttext
        </span>
    </p>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div class="headline-wrapper">
    <img class="headline-image" src="http://kcdn.at/company/84085/1073352/logo-fairmoney-clever-consulting-gmbh.companybig.gif">
    <p class="headline-title">
        <span>
            Assistant&nbsp;Manager
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.headline-wrapper {
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.headline-wrapper > .headline-image {
    width: 298px;
    height: 92px;
    align-self: center;
}
.headline-wrapper > .headline-title {
    font: 30px/1.1 Verdana;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
.headline-wrapper > .headline-title > span {
    display: table-caption;
}
```

**Result**
[image: result of https://jsfiddle.net/9888d4tf/1/]

---

The key is, that you previously need to know which words you don't want to wrap. You then either wrap them in a `white-space:nowrap` span or replace the spaces in between with `&nbsp;`as I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can set relative width for description div with percentage(like `width: 50%`). I think it would look good based on your images.